# store image in database using stored procedure in delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

I Write a SQL Server stored procedure to insert image in table.
 my stored procedure @fPhoto data type is image. There is an Error Where i command it Error. What is the problem with my code?

```
    DM.Connection.StartTransaction;
    DM.SP.StoredProcName := 'ProInsert;1';
    DM.SP.PrepareSQL(False);

    DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPName').Value := NameEdit.Text;
    DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPUnit').Value := UnitCMB.ItemIndex + 1;
    DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPType').Value := TypeCMB.ItemIndex + 1;
    DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPPrice').Value := PriceEdit.Text;

    if ProImage.Picture.Graphic = nil then
     (DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPhoto') as TBlobField) .Clear //Error
    else
     begin
      F := (DM.SP.FieldByName('@fPhoto') as TBlobField);
      S := TStream.Create;
      try
        S := DM.SP.CreateBlobStream(F, bmWrite);
        ProImage.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(S);
      finally
        S.Free;
      end;
     end;
```

[dcc32 Error] AddProUnit.pas(94): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TUniParam' and 'TBlobField'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ParamByName` instead of `FieldByName`

With UniDAC you can use `LoadFromFile` or `LoadFromStream` for Blob parameters like this :

```
 if ProImage.Picture.Graphic <> nil then
  begin
   MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
    ProImage.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(MS);

    DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPhoto').LoadFromStream(MS, ftGraphic);
    // OR DM.SP.ParamByName('@fPhoto').LoadFromFile('MyFileAddress', ftGraphic);
   finally
    MS.Free
   end;
  end;
```